# update mysql with ajax and php (using jquery)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

The code below is responsible for updating a column of a MySQL database with the selected status. After selecting the status, the user clicks the submit button and the query is executed. However, to display the new status on the screen, it is necessary to refresh the page.

I read a bit about AJAX and I think it's possible to put the PHP script aside and send the information with AJAX so that the new status changes after the user clicks the "Change" button, without refresh the page.

I learned how to send text variables through AJAX, but I also need to send the checkbox selection.

Would anyone know how to write AJAX code?

```
//the select where the user set the status

    <label>Selecione o status:</label>
    <select name="changePed">
        <option value="separacao">Em Separação</option>
        <option value="separado">Separado</option>
        <option value="faturado">Faturado</option>
        <option value="exp">Expedido</option>
        <option value="entrg">Mercadoria Entregue</option>
        <option value="cancelado">Cancelado</option>            
    </select>
    <button type="submit" >Alterar</button>
<?php
    echo "<table id='pedidos' class='table table-hover table-responsive'>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th><input type='checkbox' name='select-all' id='select-all' /></th>
                <th>Data</th>
                <th>EMS</th>
                <th>Pedido do  cliente</th>
                <th>Cliente</th>
                <th>Valor</th>
                <th>Aut. Comercial</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Nota Fiscal</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultFIL))
            {
            $dataped = $row['emissaoPed'];
              $valorped = $row['vlr'];
              echo "<tbody><tr>";
              echo "<td><input name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' value=" . $row['id'] . "></td>";
              echo "<td>" . date('d/m/Y', strtotime($dataped)) . "</td>";
              echo "<td><a id='ver_pedido' data-ref=".$row['nPedido']." data-toggle='modal' id='abremodal' href='#myModal'>" . $row['nPedido'] . "</a></td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['NrPedido'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['nomeAbrev'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . number_format($valorped, 2, ',', '.') . "</td>";
              echo "<td><input type='button' value='Autorizado' name='autCom' ></td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td><input type='text' placeholder='0012345' style='width: 70px;'>&nbsp<button type='submit' class='btn'><i class='fa fa-check' aria-hidden='true'></i></button></td> ";
              echo "</tr></tbody>";


}
 echo "</table>";
?>
 <?php 
 //The current php script that executes the query to update the database

        switch($_POST['changePed']){
            case 'separacao':
            function filter( $dados ){
                $arr = Array();
                foreach( $dados AS $dado ) $arr[] = (int)$dado;
                return $arr;
            }     
            if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
                $arr = filter( $_POST['checkbox'] );
                $sql = 'UPDATE pedidos SET status="Em separação" WHERE id IN('.implode( ',', $arr ).')';
                $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
            }
            break;
            case 'cancelado':
            function filter( $dados ){
                $arr = Array();
                foreach( $dados AS $dado ) $arr[] = (int)$dado;
                return $arr;
            }     
            if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
                $arr = filter( $_POST['checkbox'] );
                $sql = 'UPDATE pedidos SET status="Cancelado" WHERE id IN('.implode( ',', $arr ).')';
                $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
            }
            break;
            case 'faturado':
            function filter( $dados ){
                $arr = Array();
                foreach( $dados AS $dado ) $arr[] = (int)$dado;
                return $arr;
            }     
            if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
                $arr = filter( $_POST['checkbox'] );
                $sql = 'UPDATE pedidos SET status="Faturado" WHERE id IN('.implode( ',', $arr ).')';
                $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
            }
            break;
            case 'exp':
            function filter( $dados ){
                $arr = Array();
                foreach( $dados AS $dado ) $arr[] = (int)$dado;
                return $arr;
            }     
            if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
                $arr = filter( $_POST['checkbox'] );
                $sql = 'UPDATE pedidos SET status="Expedido" WHERE id IN('.implode( ',', $arr ).')';
                $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
            }
            break;
            case 'exc':
            function filter( $dados ){
                $arr = Array();
                foreach( $dados AS $dado ) $arr[] = (int)$dado;
                return $arr;
            }     
            if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
                $arr = filter( $_POST['checkbox'] );
                $sql = 'DELETE FROM pedidos WHERE id IN('.implode( ',', $arr ).')';
                $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
            }
            break;
            case 'entrg':
            function filter( $dados ){
                $arr = Array();
                foreach( $dados AS $dado ) $arr[] = (int)$dado;
                return $arr;
            }     
            if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
                $arr = filter( $_POST['checkbox'] );
                $sql = 'UPDATE pedidos SET status="Mercadoria Entregue" WHERE id IN('.implode( ',', $arr ).')';
                $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
            }
            break;
            case 'separado':
            function filter( $dados ){
                $arr = Array();
                foreach( $dados AS $dado ) $arr[] = (int)$dado;
                return $arr;
            }     
            if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
                $arr = filter( $_POST['checkbox'] );
                $sql = 'UPDATE pedidos SET status="Separado" WHERE id IN('.implode( ',', $arr ).')';
                $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
            }
            break;
        };
        ?>
```

I tried this code but it did not work:

```
function altera_status()
{

//get the datas on respective fields
var dadosajax = {
    'changePedi' : $("#changePed").val(),
    'checkbox' : $(".checkped").val(),
};
pageurl = 'status.php';
//page where is the php script

$.ajax({

    //url of actual page
    url: pageurl,
    data: dadosajax,
    type: 'POST',
    //cache
    cache: false,
    //if get an error on call
    error: function(){
        alert('Erro: Inserir Registo!!');
    },
    //response of data sended
    success: function(response)
    { 

    }
});
```

}

And the status.php is this

```
  <?php  
               //Conexão à base de dados
             $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "table_orders") or die ("Forninho fall"); 

               //recebe os parâmetros

             $change = $_REQUEST['changePedi'];
             $checki = $_REQUEST['checki'];
             print_r($change );
             switch($change){
                case 'separacao':
                function filter( $dados ){
                    $arr = Array();
                    foreach( $dados AS $dado ) $arr[] = (int)$dado;
                    return $arr;
                }     
                if(isset($checki)){
                    $arr = filter( $checki );
                    $sql = 'UPDATE pedidos SET status="Em separação" WHERE id IN('.implode( ',', $arr ).')';
                    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
                }
                break;
                case 'cancelado':
                function filter( $dados ){
                    $arr = Array();
                    foreach( $dados AS $dado ) $arr[] = (int)$dado;
                    return $arr;
                }     
                if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
                    $arr = filter( $_POST['checkbox'] );
                    $sql = 'UPDATE pedidos SET status="Cancelado" WHERE id IN('.implode( ',', $arr ).')';
                    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
                }
                break;
                case 'faturado':
                function filter( $dados ){
                    $arr = Array();
                    foreach( $dados AS $dado ) $arr[] = (int)$dado;
                    return $arr;
                }     
                if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
                    $arr = filter( $_POST['checkbox'] );
                    $sql = 'UPDATE pedidos SET status="Faturado" WHERE id IN('.implode( ',', $arr ).')';
                    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
                }
                break;
                case 'exp':
                function filter( $dados ){
                    $arr = Array();
                    foreach( $dados AS $dado ) $arr[] = (int)$dado;
                    return $arr;
                }     
                if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
                    $arr = filter( $_POST['checkbox'] );
                    $sql = 'UPDATE pedidos SET status="Expedido" WHERE id IN('.implode( ',', $arr ).')';
                    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
                }
                break;
                case 'exc':
                function filter( $dados ){
                    $arr = Array();
                    foreach( $dados AS $dado ) $arr[] = (int)$dado;
                    return $arr;
                }     
                if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
                    $arr = filter( $_POST['checkbox'] );
                    $sql = 'DELETE FROM pedidos WHERE id IN('.implode( ',', $arr ).')';
                    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
                }
                break;
                case 'entrg':
                function filter( $dados ){
                    $arr = Array();
                    foreach( $dados AS $dado ) $arr[] = (int)$dado;
                    return $arr;
                }     
                if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
                    $arr = filter( $_POST['checkbox'] );
                    $sql = 'UPDATE pedidos SET status="Mercadoria Entregue" WHERE id IN('.implode( ',', $arr ).')';
                    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
                }
                break;
                case 'separado':
                function filter( $dados ){
                    $arr = Array();
                    foreach( $dados AS $dado ) $arr[] = (int)$dado;
                    return $arr;
                }     
                if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
                    $arr = filter( $_POST['checkbox'] );
                    $sql = 'UPDATE pedidos SET status="Separado" WHERE id IN('.implode( ',', $arr ).')';
                    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
                }
                break;
             };

             ?>
```

Comment: "Would anyone know how to write AJAX code?" Well, yes.  But that's not likely to get many takers.  First, show some of the ajax you've tried, showing what specific thing is not working the way you want.

Comment: @TimMorton, Hi Tim, thanks for the advice, I edited the question with the code I had tried

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: What do you mean by "_I tried this code but it did not work_"? What did you expect to happen that didn't? were there any errors (both in the browser console and/or PHP error log, other logs, etc.)?

Comment: Hi @SamOnela. I've  rewrote the ajax and put a console.log to know what values are being get. The `'changePedi' : $("#changePed").val(),` is picking values  from `select` correctly, however the `'checkbox': $ (" # checkped "). Val ()`, is get the value of the first checkbox, regardless of whether it is selected or not. Note: these checkboxes are generated by a php script, and their values are the id of mySQL rows (`echo "<td><input id='checkped' name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' value=" . $row['id'] . "></td>";`)

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any checkbox inputs in the sample HTML - only `<select>`. Please edit your post to include those inputs ... And are you using `$('input:checkbox:checked').val()` or `$ (" # checkped "). Val ()` to get the values of checked checkboxes...?

Comment: @SamOnela, I added the code responsible for creating the checkboxes. I'm using the `'checkbox' : $(".checkped").val()` and the value return in change log is `226` (the value of the id of the first entry in mysql)

Comment: Did you switch from using the [id selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors) to using a [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors)? it doesn't appear that the checkboxes in your sample code have that class name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code.

```js
$('#SubBtn').click(function(){
  var checkboxValues = $.map($('.checkbox:checked'), function(e){
      return $(e).val();
      }).join();
  $.ajax({
    url: '',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      changePed: $('[name=changePed]').val(),
      checkbox: checkboxValues,
    }
  }).done(function(result){
      alert('success');
  }).fail(function(){
      alert('error');
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Selecione o status:</label>
    <select name="changePed">
        <option value="separacao">Em Separação</option>
        <option value="separado">Separado</option>
        <option value="faturado">Faturado</option>
        <option value="exp">Expedido</option>
        <option value="entrg">Mercadoria Entregue</option>
        <option value="cancelado">Cancelado</option>            
    </select>
    1<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="1">
    2<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="2">
    3<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="3">
    <button type="submit" id="SubBtn">Alterar</button>
```

If you want pass a list value by AJAX, you can join it by JavaScript at first.

Comment: Dear @gxvv thanks for your answer. But didnt' work for me.The checkboxes are generated automatically by this code (`echo "<td><input id='checkped' name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' value=" . $row['id'] . "></td>";`) and its values are the MySQL IDs. I needed to send these IDs to the status.php page, so the query could make the changes: /

Comment: If you want to get multiple checkbox value, you can't use the ID selector(#checped). I will edit my code later.